# Getting results from internet speed test into survey123

Tags: arcgis-survey123, speed

I have a survey made in Survey123 Connect that lets people fill in some information. I would like them to run an internet speed test and then have those results (upload/download/jitter/ping/ip) populated into the feature class. How do I get that results string into the feature class?

Comment: Is the survey designed to collect information on the internet speed test, or this is the prior requirement to fill this survey?

Comment: Ideally, they would have 2 options. 1-Run the speed test and those parameters from the results url would populate the feature class. 2-Don't run the speed test, and answer the questions in the survey and those results would populate the same feature class.

Comment: So, are you planning to give them some predefined test URL or they can use any web-based test, or through manual machine-specific commands?

Comment: We have a speed test they can run that will record the info.